# What do I have to take care of when switching from ws:// to wss://

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, websocket

I found out that some mobile network providers do not natively support port 80, but they do indeed support port 443, which I find is a bit weird.
Anyway, there's not much one can do about that which leads me to switching from port 80 to port 433, using `wss://` in favor of `ws://`.

I would like to know if using `wss://` has any negative impacts?
The issue is that I do not (yet) own a SSL-certificate.

Comment: It's not that the operator doesn't support port 80. It's that they have a proxy which interferes with the WebSocket connection when it's not encrypted. What is most probably happening is that they are interfering with the initial HTTP handshake and injecting HTTP headers or even body content. This results in a failed handshake and thus a failed connection.

Comment: To test if @leggetter is right, try running the websocket on a port like 6060 and connect to it via your mobile device using `ws://mytestmachine.com:6060/endpoint`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the only real "negative" impact might be a slight increase in CPU utilization needed to do the encryption/decryption of the content you are sending.  some of this can be offset by choosing a weaker (re:faster) cipher or in extreme cases, using an SSL hardware-based offload. there's also just a little added latency in establishing the connection (similar to using HTTPS of course) because of the TLS key exchange.  but because the key-exchange handshake only needs to happen once on the connection, it's not such a big cost overall.

as you've noted, you'll also need to get appropriate SSL certs so this will be an added administrative cost (both in $$ if you get it signed by a recognized certificate authority and a bit of time in loading it up into some keystore).

agreed with phil (@leggetter) above, most of the mobile providers are using caching proxies to speed up responses on port 80 requests (assuming that it's http content flowing over it) and it often interferes with the original http response handshake of WS.  when you use encryption, the proxies can't parse/decrypt the content anyway, so they let it pass-thru.  this is why port 443 often works where port 80 won't.  you could also try using your WS connection on a port other than 80 but only if your users are not behind firewalls.  the mobile networks don't often cache/interfere on alternate ports.

Comment: +1 - good points about the increased CPU utilization and the cost of the cert.